# Javascript unable to delete a member property from a member function

Tags: javascript

I have an object like this.

```
var v= {
    a: 1,
    delete: () => delete this.a,
}
```

I am not able to delete `a` after executing `v.delete`

Comment: Also relevant: [Self-references in object literals / initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers)

Comment: For this you need a normal function `delete: function()` or a shorthand method `delete()`. Arrow function will not have `this` equal to the current object but equal to the context wherever that object was created.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var v= {
    a: 1,
    delete: function(){delete this.a}
}

console.log("before=" + v.a)
v.delete()
console.log("after="v.a)
```

Arrow function doesn't have access to this context of the current object.

Answer (score 1):

You need convert arrow to function to use this keyword.

Also you did not call delete method to delete property.

```js
var v= {
    a: 1,
    delete: function () {
      delete this.a
    }
}

v.delete()

console.log(v)
```